# Load nuget package and its assembly in runtime

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm developing a CMF system, using asp.net 5. I think what i should implement plugin system using nuget packages, because of dnx principle "NuGet all the things".

1. How i can search, download, unpack package in runtime?
2. And how i can load dll from package in runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there is no easy way to load NuGet packages dynamically. Actually, it is not even recommended because some features like servicing will not work correctly.

You have to take the old approach: load DLLs with Reflection. If they come from a `nupkg` then you have to extract it yourself and resolve the dependencies.

Comment: Ok, this is clear, thank you . Then i want ask about future.

My scenario is multitenancy application where each tenant should have its own set of packages located in dedicated folders. For example application has two tenants. Administrator of each tenant can find, load and activate some nuget-based plugins. System must download needed packages, resolve dependencies (and download additional packages for resolve dependencies), unpack packages into tenant folder and after that system can load assemblies by Assembly.LoadFrom. (without reload application)...

Comment: ...but this looks like functionality of Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager. And I think what appropriate class for load assembly from package is NuGetAssemblyLoader. 

What plans for providing API of PackageManager for developers (and when)?

Comment: Perhaps this would help you out: https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/blob/dev/samples/Runtime.CustomLoader/Program.cs

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use the nuget.exe directly using Process.Start to download the nuget packages and install them. Then you can load assemblies from those installed packages using Assembly.LoadFrom.

Comment: This looks as old-style approach. New asp.net-5 has 
Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.*

Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager.*

and Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager.Restore.NuGet.*

I think we should use this instruments for work with NuGet packages.